# Is there a way to stream data to amazon s3 files using aws-sdk-go that is similar to google storage Write() method?

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3, google-cloud-storage, aws-sdk-go

We're currently doing a transition from Google Storage to Amazon S3 storage.

On  Google Storage I've used this function https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/storage#Writer.Write to write to files. It basically streams bytes of data into file using io.Writer interface and saves file when Close() is called on writer. That allows us to stream data into a file all day long and finalize it on the end of the day without ever creating a local copy of the file.

I've examined aws-sdk-go s3 documentation on godoc and can't seem to find a similar function that would allow us to just stream data to file without creating a file locally first. All I've found are functions that stream data from already existing local files like PutObject().

So my question is: Is there a way to stream data to amazon s3 files using aws-sdk-go that is similar to google storage Write() method?

Comment: Did you look at CloudFront? Which allows to stream s3 content?

Comment: It seems to me that CloudFront is mostly used for media files, I need a way to stream text to simple text files. Is CloudFront appropriate for that?

Comment: You are correct, @S.Drazic.  The other commenter assumes you're talking about downloads, rather than uploads.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The S3 HTTP API doesn't have any `append`-like write method, instead it uses [multipart uploads](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/mpuoverview.html). You basically upload fixed size chunks with an index number and S3 will store them internally as separate files and automatically concatenate them when the last chunks is received. Default chunk size is 5MB (can be changed) and you can have atmost 10,000 chunks (can't be changed).

Unfortunately it doesn't look like the `aws-sdk-go` API provides any convenient interface for working with chunks to achieve the streaming behaviour.

You would have to work with the chunks manually (called `parts` in `aws-sdk-go`) directly using [CreateMultipartUpload](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/s3/#S3.CreateMultipartUpload) to initialize the transfers, create [UploadPartInput](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/s3/#S3.UploadPartInput) instances for the data you want to send and send it with [UploadPart](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/s3/#S3.UploadPart). When the final chunk has been sent you need to close the transaction with [CompleteMultipartUpload](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/s3/#S3.CompleteMultipartUpload).

Regarding the question on how to stream directly from e.g. `[]byte` data instead of a file: the `Body` field of the [UploadPartInput](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/s3/#S3.UploadPartInput) struct is where you put your content you want to send to S3, note that `Body` is of type `io.readseeker`. This means you can create a `io.readseeker` from e.g. your `[]byte` content with something like [bytes.NewReader([]byte)](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#NewReader) and set `UploadPartInput.Body` to that.

The [s3manager](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/blob/master/service/s3/s3manager/upload.go) upload utility of uploads could be a good starting point to see how the multipart functions are used, it uses the multipart API to upload a single large file as smaller chunks concurrently.

Keep in mind that you should set a [lifecycle policy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/mpuoverview.html#mpu-abort-incomplete-mpu-lifecycle-config) that removes unfinished multipart uploads. If you don't send the final `CompleteMultipartUpload` all the chunks that have been uploaded will stay in S3 and incur costs. The policy can be set through AWS console/CLI or programmatically with `aws-sdk-go`.

Comment: This is essentially *the* solution. I've used it with success in the past, for streaming backups into S3 as in a pattern like `tar -c | bzip2 -9 | pipe2s3 [options]` where I didn't have the available temp space to save the backups locally.  I abandonded developing the `pipe2s3` project and never released it because there was no way to store metadata about the length of the object, final sha256, etc., because the multipart upload API requires all metadata be specified at start. (Now, of course, with object tagging, this could be done.) But this method does work and is essentially the only way.

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed answer! This seems to be the solution to my problem, I'll try it out and report back here.

Comment: @S.Drazic I added a note on lifecycle management for the bucket